# Asking questions similar to this, to build up knowledge

Tags: support, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions, questions

I just recently asked [Word-type in this sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46189/word-type-in-this-sentence).

I don't want to flood english.stackexchange without asking first. I wanted to know if it would be okay to continue asking questions similar to this?  These questions I believe are really going to help me in solidifying my knowledge of word-types in English.

Comment: I think it's fine as long as you show some research or thought in future questions. That is, apply what you learned from one question to a future question do you can solidify your knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine to me: no downvotes, no close votes, a couple of useful answers.

Also see this blog post about "[Proofreading Questions](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/on-proofreading-questions/)": the problem with bad proofreading questions are they don't teach the author anything and they'll just come back and ask another proofreading question tomorrow.

But if you're asking how the language works to learn how to use it, I think that's fine.

Reminder from the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:
>
> - Usage, word choice, and grammar
> - Etymology (history of words’ development)
> - Dialect differences
> - Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Problems encountered by people learning English